# How to create a boolean array where the value is based on an array of indices?

Tags: python, numpy

Let say I have a numpy array `A` as follows:

```
A = 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [0, 1]])
```

I created a boolean array `B` using `np.zeros` as follows

```
B = 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Now, I wanted to create an array `C`, where it gives True value based on the column index of `A`.

So,

```
C = 
array([[True, False, True],
       [False, True, True],
       [True, True, False]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using some Numpy's relatively advanced indexing techniques:

```
In [27]: B[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None], A] = True                                                                                                                                                  

In [28]: B                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[28]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

The `np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None]` creates the following array

```
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

to be used as indices for the first axis of the `B` array. The `[:,None]` here is used to transform the one-dimensional `range` object into a two dimensional array to match with the second axis indices (`A` array ) which is 2 dimensional.